# Remove specific class from class

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="electro-price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
                CHF
            </span>
            59.90
        </bdi>
    </span> – 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
            CHF
        </span>
        79.90
    </bdi>
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to remove the class "woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol" but only the last one. So the first class has to display and the second class (79.90) should not be visible.

This is in a loop, and will be printed 40 times. There are also products with only 1 "CHF" attribute.

I tried already with nth-child. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use `:nth-child` or `:last-child` on the `.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol` class because it is always the last element inside the `<span>` or `<bdi>` element. You have to use `:last-child` or `nth-child` on the parent (with class `.woocommerce-Price-amount`) like this:

```css
span.woocommerce-Price-amount:last-child span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="electro-price">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>59.90</bdi>
  </span> – 
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>79.90</bdi>
  </span>
</span>
```

If you want to show just the first currency info of the list you can use `:not` with `:nth-child` or `:first-child` like this to hide the other currency information:

```css
span.woocommerce-Price-amount:not(:nth-child(1)) span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}

/** or */

span.woocommerce-Price-amount:not(:first-child) span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="electro-price">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>59.90</bdi>
  </span> – 
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>79.90</bdi>
  </span>
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>59.90</bdi>
  </span> – 
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>79.90</bdi>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a loop :( If there is a loop of this prices, only the first one is displayed

Comment: @J.H I can't see a loop. Can you give a example with multiple items?

Comment: change the `last-child` to `:not(:first-child)` and it should work just fine again

Comment: @SebastianBrosch thank you, the solution of Ramon seems to work